# Activity indicator not in center of the subview (which is not same size as parentview)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to center a spinner in the middle of the page using the code below.

```
self.aSpinner.center = self.view.center;
```

However when when I run the program, the spinner does not seem to be in the center

[image: Screen shot of iPad simulator; activity indicator in blank view to right of center]

Is there any way to fix this?

EDIT:

I found the problem. It's not that the spinner is not in the center, but instead the subview has different bounds than its superview.

[image: Screenshot of iPad simulator; view with subviews and activity indicator to right of center]

I am doing something like this in my code:

```
self.navcon = [[UINavigationController alloc]init];
self.photoViewTable = [[PhotoTableViewController alloc]init];
self.loadingPage = [[LoadingPageViewController alloc]init];

[self.photoViewTable.view addSubview:loadingPage.view];

[navcon pushViewController:photoViewTable animated:NO];
[self.window addSubview:navcon.view];
```

How can I set the size of `loadingPage` view to be equal to the parent view?

Comment: Are you sure your view is centered? Can you provide some more code context?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[spinner setCenter:CGPointMake(kScreenWidth/2.0, kScreenHeight/2.0)];
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting the center properties might not be enough. In case your frame is being resize i will also set the autoresize mask of the spinner view:

```
spinner.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                                              UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                                              UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
                                              UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);
spinner.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds)/2, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds)/2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try do it on ViewDidAppear, there is correct self.bounds of view
I don't check self.center.

```
self.aSpinner.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.width/2.0, self.view.bounds.width/2.0)
```

Work correct!
Check self has view or self is view